# How to vertically center bootstrap column text?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, vertical-alignment

I want to display the text (and if the image is smaller, then the image) in the middle by vertically. But i can't accomplish it. Any help?

Here is what i have right now: [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7goLo3xy/1/)

HTML:

```
<div class="container overview-sm">   
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
            <div class="box2">
                <img class="image" src="http://via.placeholder.com/450x450">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
            <div class="box2">
                <h1 class="content-title">Lorem impsum</h1>
                <hr>
                <p class="content-sub-title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla sit amet purus ac turpis finibus auctor. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Donec in dictum arcu, dapibus porta lorem. </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.box2 {
    margin: 5px 5px 5px 0;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}
.image{
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 450px;
}
.row{
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}
```

Image of what i want it to be: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uE8G0.jpg)

Comment: What do you mean by vertically in the middle? Middle of where?

Comment: Middle of the row. When the image is  higher then the text, then the text stays on the top of the row, but i want it to be middle of the row height.

Comment: Also added image of what i want it to be to the post.

Comment: Can you use flexbox?

Comment: Haven't heard about it before, i will try. Any tips?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would be to use Flexbox. Note that older browsers may not have great/any Flexbox support: https://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox)

If you are using Bootstrap 4, its grid uses Flexbox, so the columns in the row should already match each other's height. You can then use Bootstrap 4's [Flexbox utility classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/#align-items) to vertically center the column's content: `class="d-flex align-items-center"`. Ex:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col d-flex align-items-center">Centered Content</div>
  <div class="col">
    <ul>
      <li>Longer</li>
      <li>Multi</li>
      <li>Line</li>
      <li>Content</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QOJjLp)

If you are using Bootstrap 3, you're going to have to add the appropriate flexbox code to both get your columns to match in height and vertically center your content. Here is a little cheatsheet I find helpful for building out flexbox layouts: http://jonibologna.com/flexbox-cheatsheet/

Edit: Here is the same example with Bootstrap 3:

HTML:

```
<div class="row row-flex">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-v-centered">Centered Content</div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <ul>
      <li>Longer</li>
      <li>Multi</li>
      <li>Line</li>
      <li>Content</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.row-flex {
  display: flex;
}
.col-v-centered {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Zambzv)

Comment: Okay, this centered the text vertically, but now when screen is smaller columns wont collapse. They stay next to each other, should go above each other.

Comment: You will need to use media queries to only add the `display: flex;` at the appropriate screen sizes. For example, if you wanted it to stack on `xs` and `sm` screens, and use the flexbox solution on `md` and `lg` screens, you would wrap the `.row-flex` class in this media query (assuming you made no changes to Bootstrap's screen size breakpoints): `@media (min-width: 992px) { .row-flex { display: flex; } }`.

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid-media-queries will give you a bit more info on the media queries Bootstrap uses. Note that the examples at that link are using LESS variables, which you won't be able to use unless you're creating a custom Bootstrap build from source.

Comment: Thank you one more time. Helps a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the text to be displayed underneath the second row then you will need to create another image div and add a class so it only displays on mobiles.

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 visible-xs ">
                <div class="box2">
                    <img class="image" src="http://via.placeholder.com/450x450">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                <div class="box2">
                    <h1 class="content-title">Lorem impsum</h1>
                    <hr>
                    <p class="content-sub-title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla sit amet purus ac turpis finibus auctor. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Donec in dictum arcu, dapibus porta lorem. </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 hidden-xs ">
                <div class="box2">
                    <img class="image" src="http://via.placeholder.com/450x450">
                </div>
            </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7goLo3xy/2/

Comment: Nope, that's not what i wanted, but good to know this tip too :) Look at the picture what i added, i want Text to be in the middle of the row.

Answer (score 0):

If you need more control than CSS provides you can use a simple jQuery or JavaScript implementable.

```
$(window).resize(function() {//on resize
    setBoxSizes();
});
function setBoxSizes() {
    $('.image').each(function() {
        let $imageBox = $(this).closest('.box2');
        let imageBoxTop = $imageBox.offset().top;
        let $otherBoxes = $imageBox.closest('.row').find('.box2');
        $otherBoxes.each(function(){
            $box = $(this);
            if(!$box.find('.image').length) {//doesn't contain .image
                if(Math.abs($box.offset().top - imageBoxTop) < 3) {//on the same layout row
                    $box.height($imageBox.height());
                }
                else $box.css('height', 'auto');//restores single column layout
            }
        });
    });
}
setBoxSizes();//initial configuration
```

**[Fiddle Example!](https://jsfiddle.net/N_Ate/Lsnejmcr/)** - Handles multiple column layout, changing columns layouts, and ensures centering is performed against equal horizon boxes.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use Flexbox you could always just set a height of 350px and use `table` and `table-cell` with `vertical-align` set to `middle`.

However this method does restrict you to having a fixed height so, if the height of your image changes the box height won't be relative. If you want the box to relative you could always set a height of 0 and use `padding-bottom`. More on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15909369/responsive-design-why-does-height-zero-padding-bottom-work-for-making-a-div-r)

```
<div class="box2">
            <div class="center">
            <div class="center-v">

                <h1 class="content-title">Lorem impsum</h1>
                <hr>
                <p class="content-sub-title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla sit amet purus ac turpis finibus auctor. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Donec in dictum arcu, dapibus porta lorem. </p>
                 </div>
                 </div> 
            </div>

.center {
    display: table;
    height: 345px;
}

.center-v {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```